# Getting the Log4j settings from a custom properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am working on a huge application which uses its on property file to set the global variables. I want to use the same one for setting the properties of Log4j log file instead of log4j.properties file due to some problems. How do I do this? Is there any way to set the properties of Log4j at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to rename your log4j.properties file you can do this using a System Variable in your JVM startup (refer [link](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/log4j/log4j_quickguide_log4jconfiguration.html))

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=test.properties
```

The [Log4j API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/index.html) also allows configuration changes to the Loggers from within an application. Theoretically you could read your own property file and call the appropriate API calls. I'm not sure this approach is recommended - you might end up spending a lot of time getting it working that you could better use developing your application functionality.

Note: I dont know the nature of the huge application, but it if its running in an application server such as JBoss they often have their own dynamic logging configuration